# Routing angular app with all-inkl Webhosting

Tags: angular, web-hosting

I have a Angular App deployed on All-Inkl Webhosting.

My Problem was I have. I can’t refresh the browser and become a blank Page in the browser.

I hope you can help me?

Comment: imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTER_CONFIG, {useHash: true}), ...

Fix my problem

Comment: Hi steffen, could I ask, how did you manage to deploy an angular app to All-Inkl webhosting?, I am trying to deploy a react app but I have no idea what to upload or what configuration is needed from all-inkl

Comment: I had only build to app and it works :)